# Change Label colour after appending it to a list

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, label

I need to be able to change the colour of a label (which is part of a grid) in Tkinter after I append it to a list, but the colour depends on if the label value is [1,5].

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
for i in range (15):
    for j in range (15):
        thegrid.append(Label(root,relief=GROOVE))
        thegrid[-1].grid(row=i,column=j)
if thegrid==[1,5]:
```

how do I change the colour of the label?

Comment: You do it the way you change anything about a widget: with the documented `configure` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `fg` & `bg` when creating the Label:

```
Label(root, relief=GROOVE, fg="red", bg="blue")
```